# Auto asynchronous orders

Tags: labview

I have a LabVIEW program that I want to change some codes in. Basically, there is a box called Target WL which moves the wavelength of a light source to a certain value (see attached pic). This is a specific value. What I want to replace it with a program where is start point and events then endpoint with layout time in between. For example,

Start Target WL ( 100)

End Target WL ( 200)

Increment ( 5)

The Idea is to do auto orders to the light source to place the order of various values with time layout between each value or event.

Can anyone explain to me where to start or the best structure I can start with please? 
I tried while loop, for loop, and flat sequence. I couldn't manage to do what I want.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Working with what you have and aiming for the easiest change, here is my suggestion: create a parallel loop that controls the target values and updates the control programmatically using a local variable.

However, if it were up to me to do, I'd start over using a more cohesive architecture better suited for extensibility ([QMH](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/53391/en/) or [Producer/Consumer](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/3023/en/) for example). At the very least you would do well to get rid of all the stacked sequence structures as they're confusing and ultimately unnecessary.